# Interfacing Arduino with Python

Tags: python, arduino

```
File "C:\Users\Musa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'com7': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5
```

Why does it show this?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10175/cant-communicate-with-arduino-using-python-windows) on the Arduino stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave the Arduino IDE's Serial Monitor open? If so, close it and try again.